# Client Certificate Authentication on Windows Server 2012/IIS8 in Microsoft Azure receives HTTP 403.16

Tags: iis, azure, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2012, client-certificates

We are developing an ASP.NET WebAPI that is hosted in IIS and authenticates using client certificates with iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication.
In our on-premises development environment we have tested IIS 7-8 and Windows 7-8/Server 2012, all of which work fine.

We have set up a demo environment in Azure with a VM running Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8. Using this configuration we have yet to successfully pass through IIS client certificate validation, where we consistently receive an HTTP 403.16 error.

The service is consumed by a custom iOS app that we have verified is sending the client certificate, which was expected since my understanding of the error implies IIS is unable to validate the certificate that it received.

The Client Certificate Authority is installed in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities and the Client Authentication Issuers stores for the Local Computer.

Pretty much all of the resources we can find on this issue propose the solution here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fae724e8-628e-45a5-bf39-6e812d8a1a70/40316-problem-in-iss8-on-mp-in-dmz?forum=configmanagerdeployment
where it's suggested we add a registry setting for ClientAuthTrustMode. This has not resolved the issue for us; we also did not need to do it for any of our local testing which involved the exact same OS and IIS versions.

We've spent days on this with no progress and were hoping someone may have some insight into this issue. Is there any default configuration that we have yet to come across to enable this form of authentication for VMs in Azure? It seems as though IIS on a VM in Azure is unable to actually validate against the CA in Trusted Root. One idea I had was that perhaps the certificate is being stripped from the request before it's routed to IIS, but again, that seems unlikely given my understanding of the error code.

Has anyone gotten a setup like this to work?

Comment: In the above mentioned article that has not worked for you, add SendTrustedIssuerList = 0, along with ClientAuthTrustMode = 2

Comment: http://configmgrblog.com/2014/02/23/configmgr-2012-r2-internet-facing-mp-windows-server-2012-r2-note/

Answer (score 0):

I happened upon this knowledge base article, maybe it can help you
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2802568